# What is the best way to auto generate getters and setters for a class in php?

Tags: php, eclipse, class, get, set

I regularly create a class that has a few private variables.
When an instance of this class is set, it should be possible to fill all variables of the class with getters and setters.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to type all these setters and getters for each variable on creation of the class?

now i have to type this for each var in the class

```
public function setVar($var){
$this->var = $var;
}
```

and

```
public function getVar(){
return $this->var;
}
```

We now use RegExp, but i don't know if this is the easiest way...
We use Eclipse as environment, so perhaps there are some usefull plugins?

Comment: Although a pain, it hardly takes much time to implement these.  I usually do em while I am eating my lunch. Better yet, pass the code off to a student to add in.

Comment: @Chris Pass it to someone else cannot be considered a good solution. A student or add-in might want to have a proper solution for this as well...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With Eclipse go to Preferences -> PHP -> Editor -> Templates -> New and use something like this:

```
/**
 * Method to get the ${PropertyName}
 *
 * @return  ${ReturnType}  return the ${PropertyName}.
 *
 * @since   __DEPLOY_VERSION__
*/
public function get${MethodName}() {
  return $$this->${PropertyName};
}

/**
 * Method to set the ${PropertyName}
 *
 * @return  boolean  True on success and false on failed case
 *
 * @since   __DEPLOY_VERSION__
*/
public function set${MethodName}($$value) {
  $$this->${PropertyName} = $$value;
}
```

To use the template type its name and press ctrl+space - a context menu should also automatically appear when you type the name.

Comment: Any fix related to the camel case usage in these properties?

Comment: @porfiriopartida I wondered about the same thing and ended up using a different variable in the get and set. When using the template, you only have to set the property and the getter function. ;-)

Comment: for Netbeans user, Preferences -> Editor -> Code Templates Tab, Language: PHP, add new

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the __set and __get methods? Don't know if this is what you mean but the are automatically called whenever a class member is SET or Retrieved/Fetched/Accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Studio has a feature of automatic getter/setter generation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use the __set and __get with some string functions, Here let me show you.

```
class UserProfile
{
    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->$key))
        {
            return $this->$key;
        }
    }

    public function __set($key,$val)
    {
        $this->cahnge($key,$val);
    }

    public function __call($key,$params)
    {
        if(substr("set",$key))
        {
            //Update
        }elseif(substr("get",$key))
        {
            //return
        }

        //Else Blah
    }

    private function change($key,$val)
    {
        if(isset($this->$key))
        {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

the __call() method will allow you to set with functions such as

`$profile->setUsername('Robert Pitt');` as long as you `substr` the set/get and check for the rest of the string as a value of the class :)

another example

```
public function __call($method,$params = array())
{

    if(isset($params[0]) && is_string($params[0]))
    {
        $this->$method = $params[0];
    }
}

//....

$profile->username('Robert Pitt');
```

Theres more work to be done here

Comment: are you sure this works? I couldn't manage it. is this some kind of PHP magic? I can call `$profile-> __get(username)` but I wanted to call `$profile-> getUsername()`

Comment: try replace `$this->cahnge($key,$val);` with `$this->change($key,$val);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better sollution:

```
class base {

    protected $_vars = array();


    public function setVar($name, $value = null) {
        $this->_vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getVar($name) {
        return isset($this->_vars[$name]) ? $this->_vars[$name] : null;
    }
}
```

And simply extend this class. Or also you can use __set and __get methods, but they are quite slower.

Comment: this might be a good solution, but is it a good idea to put all in an array, and not all as different vars? or doesn't that matter?

Comment: If it is working data (like arrays, strings, etc.) it's OK. But if you want to set some objects like database object or others, you shouldn't do this way. Then use constructors or other ways.

Comment: Are you sure about __set and __get mehods being slow??

Comment: @andho Yes, I'm pretty sure. Sorry, I can't find the article about how PHP works with memory when using magic methods (I've read before a while), but if You search, there are written almost on every list of "PHP performance tips" that magic methods can slow down your code.