# How to generate getter and setter in eclipse (php)

Tags: php, eclipse

Usually, I use eclipse to work with Java, so when I want to work with PHP, I use eclipse too.

But I don't know how to generate getter and setter for class variables. When I do a right click, I don't have the menu `Source -> Generate Getter / Setter`.

How to do this with php in eclipse ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Enrico Sure he can, but what's the point of using an IDE then?

Comment: Yes Enrico, I can do this but it's a come back when you use eclipse with java ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to auto generate getters and setters for a class in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476419/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-getters-and-setters-for-a-class-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend Studio, which is based on Eclipse, provides this feature as well. It is not free, however, but if you don't mind paying for an IDE, this might be an option.

If you're currently using PHP, you might find this comparison between PDT and Zend Studio useful:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison

Comment: I know Zend Studio but I thought eclipse can do this. I think I'll use Zend Studio ;)

Answer (score 13):

I was looking for something similar to these two alternatives. I found one that is free and seems to be updated regularly, so I'm leaving the link here for others to come: [PDT Extensions](http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/)(and the [snapshot](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/) version).

And here's the [gitub](https://github.com/pdt-eg/Core-Plugin) site.

> Addons for the eclipse PHP development tools. Provides code formatting and code generation like
>
> - getter/setter generation
> - new class wizard
> - interface method implementation
> - and other features

Comment: The link provided is the snapshot link, here is the stable link: http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/

Answer (score 12):

It seems like the [E-surf plugin](http://pdt.plugins.e-surf.pl) is what you need. From the [features page](http://pdt.plugins.e-surf.pl/features.php):

> The main features added in 1.0.0 (current) version:
>   - Possibility to handle multiple PHP classes in one source file
>   - Additional generated methods sort mode (first setters, then getters)
>   - Improved main menu access - only when a suitable PHP editor is available

Answer (score 9):

A good answer is here: [What is the best way to auto generate getters and setters for a class in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476419/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-getters-and-setters-for-a-class-in-php)

Create a template then you can use CTRL+Shift to execute it

```
private $$${PropertyName};
${cursor}    
public function get${PropertyName}() 
{
  return $$this->${PropertyName};
}

public function set${PropertyName}($$value) 
{
  $$this->${PropertyName} = $$value;
}
```

Thanks erisco for the great answer

Answer (score 3):

This can help, it is a plugin to generate code in PHP. 
http://pdt.plugins.e-surf.pl/install.php

Answer (score 2):

I found this Plugin very useful: http://loge5.de/phpgen

It supports comments, "Fluid Interface" and some other stuff.
Quite simple and clear but **more powerful than the E-Surf** plugin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question was how to generate getter/setter for PHP-classes in Eclipse. And with this plugin you can do that. So what did i wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That plugin helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit late to answer this question, but I was searching for this today and found out a plugin that could be installed from eclipse URL: http://pdt.plugins.e-surf.pl/updates/

Answer (score 0):

I know what you wanted cos I was exactly the same scenario... learnt Java in Eclipse then moved to other languages and missed that feature so I wrote this in PHP. So you don't have to change editors just to get that one feature. It also works for VB as that was what I originally created it for...

You can download it here: https://github.com/aosiname/Generate-Getters-and-Setters