# Automatic Getter and Setter Performance options instead of __call

Tags: php, oop

I am looking at options to not having to write getter and setters in my code.

Currently I am using __call to automatically map getters and setters to my properties, however I have been informed that that is very slow.

What options do I have, because writing getters and setters to return properties only is not a very good use of our developer time, and maintaining them is more of a headache

Comment: some ide's can do it for you. code generation is under utilized imo.

Answer (score 2):

While `__call()` might not be great in performance, the only alternative I see for you is code generation from an IDE. This also improves the code insight features many recent editors have, allowing the editor to suggest method names while you type code; very handy stuff!

See also: [How to generate getter and setter in eclipse (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238174/how-to-generate-getter-and-setter-in-eclipse-php)

Btw - the `__get()` and `__set()` will probably have the same performance issues and introducing them now will dramatically change your existing code (not a good idea).

**Edit**

I couldn't find any good articles that talk about how to maintain getters and setters dynamically, so I thought of another way (which may or may not work for you).

You could write a code transformer that takes care of the maintenance for you by using either `tokenizer` or `Reflection` (or both). This should then be integrated in the IDE as you save it, or it has to be done dynamically every time the file changed.

Anyway, just an idea :)

Comment: The IDE can generate the getters and setters for me, yes, but since I am working in an iterative based development environment, the changes are "high speed", so we may find that 40 - 50% of the properties may change, as we move. Keeping the docblocks up-to-date is a challenge

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use __set(), and __get(), or make public attributes. I haven't heard about any other "magic" methods to do this.

Comment: That would change the existing code; imagine having to rename all your `->getVariable()` to `->variable` ... this gets even worse when others are using your API

Comment: The reason I am not going for public attributes is to use the getters and setters to carry out any transformations and/or validations that may be needed as the project evolves

Comment: So I guess that only methods generated from IDE will do the trick.